# Make a floating box anchored to text using inline code

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to make an Organizer, including a weekly planner, based on one I found on the net using tex. I've managed, until now, to make some changes to adapt it to my needs and, for example, include my country holydays next to the day and month on the weekly planner. Now I'm trying to make a grey shadow behind the day planning lines only on the holydays and Sundays. This planner uses a python program to make the year macros and it would be easier for me to include this "shadow" anchored to the holyday text and using inline code.
Is there any way to do this?

the macro is something like this:

```
% Weekly Planner macros for 2019


\LeftPageWP{1}{31 Dezembro - \scriptsize{Véspera de Ano Novo}}{1 Janeiro - \scriptsize{Ano Novo}}{2 Janeiro}{3 Janeiro}
\RightPageHeaderWP{Dezembro 2018 -- Janeiro 2019}
\RightPageWP{4 Janeiro}{5 Janeiro}{6 Janeiro}{Dezembro}{\MonthTblDecPrev}{Janeiro}{\MonthTblJan}{Fevereiro}{\MonthTblFeb}
```

This "macro" is then used by a weekly planner tex file and then by a main tex file.

My idea was to include this "shadow" code inline on the macro file itself, next to the name of the holyday (`\scriptsize{Ano Novo}`) in order for it to be read by the tex processor.

the picture of what I want is something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I am completely lost. Please provide us with am minimal working example, i.e. a compilable document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and illustrates your point.

Comment: I think it's too complex and I don't know how to make a minimal example, I need to know if there is a way to make a shadow behind the text, using inline code (in order to include it in the macro) and anchor this shadow to the text in order to put it in the right place on the page.

Comment: I send here the important files:
[DYI_Weekly_Planner.tex](https://pastebin.com/WJFhtLQc)
[DYI_Main.tex](https://pastebin.com/y1LEsWFZ)

Comment: `(\scriptsize{Ano Novo}) ` would make a full size  ( but a script size ) and all following text

Comment: This example is only the macros, not the full file...

Comment: Where can I download this?